# Find all idempotent elements in the group algebra $\mathbb CC_3$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, idempotents, algebras

Sorry but I'm quite new to group algebras and even Latex so if this is all wrong I apologize.
By $\mathbb CC_3$ I mean the group algebra of the cyclic group of order 3 in the complex numbers

A group algebra is a ring so is it best to say $C_3$ has elements $e$, $a$ and $b$ instead of thinking of C3 having a generator g because the group action would be written + and if we said $C_3$ had elements $e$ $g$ and $2g$ that's pretty ambiguous because in $\mathbb CC_3$ $2g$ means something quite different right? Similarly if we wrote the group binary relation multiplicatively and said $C_3$ had elements $e$, $g$ and $g^2$ that would also be troublesome because we're working in a ring with + and *, right? (although in this specific example it would work out okay since $2*2=2+2$)

but I mean the point is if the elements are $e$ (the identity), $a$ and $b$, we think of them as e=0, a=1 and b=2 with addition and multiplication mod 3 yes? I'm just reluctant to actually call the elements 0,1,2 because it would look somewhat confusing in the group algebra, right?

When we say that $\mathbb CC_3$ is a group algebra we mean it's just a set of finite linear combinations of the form $Ae + Ba + Cb$ where $A,B,C$ belong to the set of complex numbers, right? The coefficients $A,B,C$ in no way at all "mean" anything with respect to the group, right? (eg, there's no way that $Ba=b$ for some $B in C$, like say B=2) right? $A. B and C$ are just symbols from the field of complex numbers and that's it, right?

How would one go about finding all the idempotent elements of this group algebra? How would you know you've found them all? Does one just solve:
$$(Ae + Ba + Cb)(Ae + Ba + Cb)=(Ae + Ba + Cb)$$
which implies
B=1 or 0 by looking at a coefficient, etc?

Comment: So the first $C$ is the complex numbers? This is often written $\mathbb C[C_3]$.

Comment: Best to write $C_3$ multiplicative, so $C_3=\{1,g,g^2\}$, and $\mathbb CC_3 = \{a\cdot 1+b\cdot g+c\cdot g^2$\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb C\}$. There is no real problem with $g^2$.

Comment: (In any event, it is not at all clear how you got $B=0,1$.)

Comment: @peter In this case, since the group algebra is a direct product of  three fields, you can count idempotents by counting the ideals of the ring. Details in the comment to Jared's answer.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95387/group-ring-calculation/153710#153710) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95387/group-ring-calculation/153710#153710

Answer (score 6):

You can also invoke the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find all idempotents. Let $\omega := \frac 1 2 (i \sqrt{3} -1)$ be a primitive third root of unity. There are canonical isomorphisms

> $\mathbb{C} C_3 \cong \mathbb{C}[X]/(X^3-1) \cong \mathbb{C}[X]/(X-1) \times \mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\omega) \times \mathbb{C}[X]/(X-\omega^2) \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$.

Now you can easily find all idempotents of $\mathbb{C}^3$ and then get those of $\mathbb{C} C_3$ by applying each isomorphism. Note that since the isomorphisms are $\mathbb{C}$-linear, it suffices to consider a basis of $\mathbb{C}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

I took the approach you mention.  If $a$ is a generator of $C_3$, and $x,y,$ and $z$ are complex numbers, then the equation $(x\cdot e+y\cdot a+z\cdot a^2)^2=x\cdot e+y\cdot a+z\cdot a^2$ gives the following system:

$$x^2+2yz=x\\y^2+2xz=z\\z^2+2xy=y$$

You can solve this by hand if you want, but Wolfram|Alpha gives [$8$ solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2b2yz=x,%20y%5E2%2b2xz=z,%20z%5E2%2b2xy=y).

I imagine there is a better way to do this.

Comment: +1 Except for the trivial solutions and the $e=(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ solution, which one might happen across by inspection, I can't see a better trick to tease out those complex solutions. The $(2/3,-1/3,-1/3)$ solution is obviously for free as it is just $1-e$. One can feel fully justified that $8$ is the right number since $\Bbb C[C_3]$ is a three dimensional commutative semisimple algebra over $\Bbb C$, and so it must be isomorphic to $\Bbb C^3$. This ring has exactly 8 ideals, which correspond exactly to the idempotents.

Comment: Note, if you add these three equations, you get $(x+y+z)^2=x+y+z$. This is generally true for any group algebra - the sum of the coefficients of an idempotent has to be $0,1$. That's because there is a simple ring homomorphism $\mathbb CG\to\mathbb C$ sending each group element to $1$.

Comment: Also, those roots are not as obscure as they look - $\frac{1}{6}i(\sqrt{3}+1) = \frac{1}{3}\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$, and $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}=\zeta_3$ is a cube root of $1$. So these idemptotents are $\frac 13(1+\zeta_3g +\zeta_3^2g^2)$ and other variations.  @rschwieb

Comment: Dear @ThomasAndrews : Certainly, but the issue is to explain why someone should recognize that *a priori*. I noticed that $(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ because I was curious about squaring $1+g+g^2$ (and noticed the result could be scaled).

Comment: But what this means is that if $\phi:C_3\to\mathbb C^\times$ is a group homomorphism, then $\frac{1}{|C_3|}(\phi(1)\cdot 1+\phi(g)\cdot g^2+\phi(g^2)\cdot g^2)$ is an idempotent. And *that* is not surprising.

Comment: @rschwieb Basically, a homomorphism $\phi:G\to \mathbb C^\times$ determines an automorphism on $\mathbb C[G]$, and the images of idempotents are idempotents.

Comment: Dear @ThomasAndrews Ah! The last two comments are very eye opening :) I had not seen this easy application of the lifting proprety of the group ring before. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @ThomasAndrews So I learned from your comments yesterday how, given an idempotent of $\Bbb C[C_3]$, one can fish out the rest by leveraging the homomorphisms $C_3\to \Bbb C^\times$. Any tricks for efficiently detecting that first idempotent? Thanks.

Comment: @rschwieb: $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}g$ is always an idempotent of $\mathbb C[G]$. Indeed, for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $\frac{1}{|H|}\sum_{g\in H}g$ is an idempotent for $\mathbb C[G]$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I would be grateful for a proof-comment, or a pointer to an explanation in text, if space prohibits a proof-comment.

Comment: It's a pretty trivial computation: $(\sum_H g)^2 = |H|\sum_H g$ pretty transparently - look at the multiplication table for $H$ - each number occurs exactly $|H|$ times. @rschwieb

Comment: Ah, so it's just simple combinatorics. That's great, thanks @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @rschwieb Cool thing to note. If $e$ is an idempotent in a not-necessarily commutative ring $R$, then you need to have $e$ commute with all the elements of $R$ for $eR$ to also be a ring. In the case of $R=\mathbb C[G]$ and $e_H=\frac 1{|H|}\sum_H g$, $e_H$ commutes with all the elements of $R$ precisely when $H$ is a normal subgroup...

Comment: @rschwieb You're right. I still think the statement is true about $e_H$. You need $e_Hge_H=e_Hg$ for all $g\in G$. That can be rewritten as $e_He_{gHg^{-1}}=e_H$. But if $gHg^{-1}$ has elements not in $H$, then it isn't possible for $e_He_{gHg^{-1}}=e_H$ - there will be non-zero coefficients for some $g_0\in G\setminus H$ on the left side.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Great: thanks for checking and writing up these nuggets. They're exactly the sort of thing I forget unless I hit upon them while doing a problem.