# Finding Idempotents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules

I was wondering if there is a method for finding primitive idempotents of a finite dimensional algebra (over a field)? or in other words is there any way to build the complete set of primitive idempotents from one (idempotent)?
Or if it is impassible to find a method,
I believe a good reference or some tricks (general notes) on idempotents is also going to be very useful to me.

Comment: Sorry I'd type more here but I gotta run to a meeting, this pdf helps me a LOT when considering idempotents in a similar nature to you (Page 3) http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/bobh/UoS/replec18.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only general method for finite dimensional algebras would be to look at a general element in the algebra and see what constraints it would have to fulfill to satisfy $x^2=x$. And of course, for any idempotent $e$, $1-e$ is an idempotent, so if you get bored with one you can jump to the other.

Of course, certain things will help simplify things. If you can decompose your ring into a direct product of rings, you know that the identities of these rings are idempotents which add up to the identity of the product ring.

Once you find a nontrivial idempotent $e$, you can compute what $eRe$ looks like. If $eRe$ is a [local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring), then you're good because $e$ is a primitive idempotent and you can move on. If it isn't local, that means $e$ must decompose in $eRe$, and so you repeat the process of finding nontrivial idempotents in $eRe$.

Now I see you've tagged the question with representation theory, so chances are good you might be working with group algebras like $F[G]$. If so, I have a few more tricks up my sleeve for you.

One of the most useful is that for any subgroup $H<G$ ($G$ finite, and let's require the characteristic of $F$ to be zero while we're at it), the sum of the elements in $H$ is an idempotent of $F[H]$. And if I remember correctly, if $H$ is normal, then the idempotent is central. This even applies to the subgroup $G$, where I believe the resulting idempotent is the identity element of $F$ in the decomposition $F[G]\cong F\oplus \omega(G)$.

Finally, for the special case of group rings over cyclic groups and $\Bbb C$, Thomas Andrews showed me some neat tricks using roots of $x^n-1$ for generating idempotents. This might be generalizable. I invite you to read about it in the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451280/find-all-idempotent-elements-in-the-group-algebra-mathbb-cc-3).

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer.

Comment: @math137 Hope it helps! If you have any more details about the type of ring you're looking at, I might be able to add something else I didn't think of.

Comment: Yes it was helpful because at least I learned that there is no general method to do this. Well, I need that to decompose a some kind of monoid algebra rather than a group algebra.

Answer (score 1):

See p28 The Theory of Group Characters and Matrix Representations of Groups by D E Littlewood. But he makes it sound difficult!